# Can Linq check if value is Null Before Regex Replace

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to replace the characters below for sorting purposes only for all of the list values. The issue is that sometimes the builtpartyname is null, and Im getting an error because its trying to do a regex replace on a null value.

Is there anyway for me to check if the BuiltPartyName value is null within the order by clause before it does the replace in the Linq statement?

```
string pattern = ".,"; //characters we dont want to be considered in the sorting of records.
string hyphenPattern = "-";

PartyListing = PartyListing.OrderBy(p => Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(p.BuiltPartyName, pattern, ""),hyphenPattern,"000000")).ToList(),
```

Comment: You are already filtering null values with .Where(p => p.BuiltPartyName != null)

Comment: Sorry that wasnt supposed to be there because I only dont want the nulls in the order by, I still want them in the list. Just pulled that out

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The code before perfectly works and eliminates null values. Where does not remove them from the list

Comment: It does, but thats not what I want. I changed the code I initially posted because I still want the null values in the list. I just dont want them to be considered in the regex replace/ order by clause part.

Comment: @user9758711, I guess you are confused about how Linq works. It does not alter the original list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string pattern = ".,"; //characters we dont want to be considered in the sorting of records.
string hyphenPattern = "-";

PartyListing = PartyListing.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.BuiltPartyName)).OrderBy(p => Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(p.BuiltPartyName, pattern, ""),hyphenPattern,"000000")).ToList(),
```

The reason this works is that you are using !=null in your where clause, but an empty string "" is not null, so you need to check for null or whitespace instead.

Or try the following:

```
string pattern = ".,"; //characters we dont want to be considered in the sorting of records.
string hyphenPattern = "-";

PartyListing = PartyListing.Where(p => p.BuiltPartyName !=null).OrderBy(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.BuiltPartyName) ? "" : Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(p.BuiltPartyName, pattern, ""),hyphenPattern,"000000")).ToList(),
```

Comment: This kinda works, but the only issue is I still want the null values to remain in the list. I just dont want them to be considered in the replace/order by part. Maybe my best option is to filter them out like you have, sort, then add them back in the front afterwards

Comment: That worked! I pulled out the where clause part because I still want the null builtpartynames in the list, but the checking if null or whitespace in the order by is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!